# Can't resize RichTextBox in IDE

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2022

For some reason, I am unable to change the size of a RichTextBox by dragging on its corners wih the mouse.

To my knowledge, the control is not locked, and Maximum Size is set to 0; 0.

What am missing?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had set the dock style to fill.
Once I removed that, it worked.